# Sublime text configuration can't find nodejs because of space in filename

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

`"windows": "C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs",`

This is what i thought would have worked, but it doesn't. I think it's due to space in between.

I installed some addon in sublimetext 3, which required nodejs. However, it says nodejs not found at specified path. Then i put the correct path. But i still get the same error.

How do you deal with this space problem... because in cli you could put it under quotes to compensate for spaces.

Comment: Try the environment variable: `"windows": "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\nodejs"`

Comment: Try escaping the spaces: `"windows": "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/nodejs"`